# Code with future in mind

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wpf, coding-style, structure

We all coders here, basically. What I'm going to ask you, is how you're struct you solution/project to reflect even in rough way the **structure** of what you develop.
How you gonna *describe*  dependency of one class from another in **code**, how you gonna structure your  solution in a way that  after a couple of years someone new to your project is able to understand (more or less) the code dependencies in your solution?

Give the first answer, just to give another hint what I'm *really* asking about:

We can use common tools/frameworks in our development: NHibernate, ASP.NET MVS, WPF... which will lead us to structure the code in several way, so someone who is familiar with that tool will understand just looking on the project of, let's say VisualStudio, how your project is basiclally structured.

P.S: I'm aware of Diagram tools, Visio or whatever, my question is: do you ever think about this from **coding prespective**?

Comment: Doesn't this assume that we're not using interfaces as a level of abstraction to minimize class dependencies?

Comment: it's not about minimizing abstraction , as about rapresent it in clear possible way, as code is just characters set and nothing more

Comment: I really doubt there is a *right* answer to this question, it's more like the start of a discussion. As per the [faq], this is not the type of question that is fitting for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Lasse: I don't agree to close this question. The question (how do I organize a project and code so that its structure and the relatonships of its parts is most easily to recognize) is unique to software development and is very answerable and faces actual problems of many developers (to quote the faqs). The fact that there might not be a unique and single possible answer (which is also the case for many programming questions) is not enough to call this a discussion. Voted for reopening.

Comment: do the @downvoter care to explain it's downvote, or just downvoting for hobby?

Comment: @Slauma The problem with questions like this is that the OP is basically asking for a lot of different answers, basically opinions, and an open-ended discussion, and then people will vote on the various points. This is not how SO works. If you want to quote the [faq], how about this: *You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.*

Comment: @Lasse: the question was in regard of architecturing the code, so I think if we think that it's discussion, it'ok by me, but let' close also other questions about architecture. I'm not agree on closing , but not protest on this :) , as none really make single comment or answer in regard, except @David, means that subject is out of interest of community, so let's close it.

Comment: +1 and voting to reopen as “ Good code is its own best documentation.” - **Steve McConnell**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to @Joakim's point in a comment above, a key way to do this really does center around abstraction.  One thing I make an effort to do in all my .NET projects is to confine external dependencies to their own projects in Visual Studio.  Those projects are injected with an IoC container (also abstracted with a service locator setup) to fulfill the abstracted interfaces.

So the central domain logic is just internal code.  No dependencies.  Basically, that project doesn't reference anything, everything references it.  It's just the business logic (models, interfaces for dependencies such as data repositories, etc.).

Then an external dependency (which could be a database by means of a data access framework, an external service of some kind, or even just a 3rd party library such as the IoC container) would be used in its own project and implement the domain interfaces that it needs to implement.  This keeps the dependencies clear and separated, so they can be easily identified and potentially replaced without ever touching the internal business logic.

Comment: this is one of the ways to "enforce" the code structure, by using IoC framework, agree. Vote for this one as it's good and also only one. Noone really cares seems on this stuff here. May be, really, it's better to make this question on faq. Thank you!